# absolute child same width as column container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating my own dropdown search bar that displays results when a user types some text.

The problem is that the result list div has to be `position: absolute`. This leads it to ignoring the parent col container width. How do I get results list to fit within the width of the col?

```css
.player-search-list {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <!-- some other content -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="top-buffer">
      <!-- Relative search bar that expands to bootstrap col -->
      <div class="player-search-bar input-group rounded-bottom-0">
        <!-- search functionality-->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ***ABSOLUTE drop down*** that doesnt fit inside bootstrap col -->
    <div class="list-group player-search-list" id="playerSearch">
      <div *ngFor="let result of results | slice:0:9">
        <!-- drop down results list functionality -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: results moved out of col]

Comment: Did you try making the parent `position:relative`?

Answer (score 1):

In Case somebody stumbles on this question and is still looking for the result:

Your Parent DIV (in this case .col-6) must be position:relative.
The width of the search results must be set to 100%!

```
parent_container {
  position: relative;
}

search_results {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
.player-search-list{
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

The `left` is to center the div inside the container. The `padding-left and padding-right` is the same amount of the col container. This keeps the divs in the same position and size of the search bar.